# need help to find correct xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I have the following this weather [site](http://www.irimo.ir/farsi/current/index.asp?station=40753)

And i need to using Xpath but icant return query!

> I'm using this xPath and must return 2 Row

```
$xpath->query('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/p/table/tbody/tr/td/font/div/center/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/font/font/b');
```

but not return anythings:

### **please complete this xpath**

**i'm using this cod butt show error**

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be
>   converted to string in /home/mysite/curl.php on line 23

```
<?php
$url="http://www.irimo.ir/farsi/current/index.asp?station=40770";
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($allcont);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

$return = $xpath->query('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/p/table/tbody/tr/td/font/div/center/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/font/b');

echo $return;
echo $xpath;

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my XPath query (scraping HTML tables) only work in Firebug, but not the application I'm developing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$xpath->query('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/p/table/tbody/tr/td/font/div/center/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/font/b');
```

Comment: work but show **error**`Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMXPath could not be converted to string in /home/Mysite` how convert to str i try  strval but dont work!!!

Comment: I need to see the line that throws this error. What are you trying to do with `$xpath`?