# App Script - Can´t Scrap Data From Html table

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, html-table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inc12.png)

I have the Html from image, but I can't have the data from tbody. tbody is child `<div><table id="grid1ContainerRow_001"><tbody>`, and the data it's organize in `<tr><td>`.

I found some scripts to get html tables, but all them get some error.

like this [Google App Script parse table from messed html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620660/google-app-script-parse-table-from-messed-html) that return  `"Open quote is expected for attribute "tabindex" associated with an  element type  "form"."`

the table shows like that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH22f.png)

And have an inconvenience because the table have next page continuation, so you need click "next page" button to have the complete data.

The site has an Excel download option, but I want to have the data direct from web site, because it's updated some times.

If you want to see, here is the site table http://secure.senave.gov.py:8443/registros/servlet/com.consultaregistros2.prod_agro2

I want a form to get the table from the html site.

**EDIT 1**

I got the data from the first page

```
 function foo() {
  var url = "http://secure.senave.gov.py:8443/registros/servlet/com.consultaregistros2.prod_agro2"
  var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().getDataAsString()
  var xd = [];
  //Logger.log(page)
  var Matrix = Parser.data(page).from(" value='").to("'/>").build();
  xd = JSON.parse(Matrix)
  plot_data_to_Spreadsheet(xd)

}
```

**NOW** I can´t scrap the complete table because it has "next" button to access the rest of them.