# Scraping from web page and reformatting to a calender file

Tags: python, xpath, calendar, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape this site: http://stats.swehockey.se/ScheduleAndResults/Schedule/3940

And I've gotten as far (thanks to alecxe) as retrieving the date and teams.

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class SchemaItem(Item):
    date = Field()
    teams = Field()


class SchemaSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "schema"
    allowed_domains = ["http://stats.swehockey.se/"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://stats.swehockey.se/ScheduleAndResults/Schedule/3940"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        rows = hxs.select('//table[@class="tblContent"]/tr')

        for row in rows:
            item = SchemaItem()
            item['date'] = row.select('.//td[2]/div/span/text()').extract()
            item['teams'] = row.select('.//td[3]/text()').extract()

            yield item
```

So, my next step is to filter out anything that ins't a home game of "AIK" or "Djurgårdens IF". After that I'll need to reformat to an .ics file which I can add to Google Calender.

EDIT: So I've solved a few things but still has a lot to do. My code now looks like this..

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class SchemaItem(Item):
    date = Field()
    teams = Field()


class SchemaSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "schema"
    allowed_domains = ["http://stats.swehockey.se/"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://stats.swehockey.se/ScheduleAndResults/Schedule/3940"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        rows = hxs.select('//table[@class="tblContent"]/tr')

        for row in rows:
            item = SchemaItem()
            item['date'] = row.select('.//td[2]/div/span/text()').extract()
            item['teams'] = row.select('.//td[3]/text()').extract()

            for string in item['teams']:

                teams = string.split('-') #split it

                home_team = teams[0]#.split(' ') #only the first name, e.g. just 'Djurgårdens' out of 'Djurgårdens IF'
                away_team = teams[1]
                #home_team[0] = home_team[0].replace(" ", "") #remove whitespace
                #home_team = home_team[0]

                if "AIK" in home_team:
                    for string in item['date']:
                            year = string[0:4]
                            month = string[5:7]
                            day = string[8:10]
                            hour = string[11:13]
                            minute = string[14:16]

                            print year, month, day, hour, minute, home_team, away_team  
                elif u"Djurgårdens" in home_team:
                    for string in item['date']:
                        year = string[0:4]
                        month = string[5:7]
                        day = string[8:10]
                        hour = string[11:13]
                        minute = string[14:16]

                        print year, month, day, hour, minute, home_team, away_team
```

That code prints out the games of "AIK", "Djurgårdens IF" and "Skellefteå AIK". So my problem here is obviously how to filter out "Skellefteå AIK" games and if there is any easy way to make this program better. Thoughts on this?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing that home games are the ones with the team you're looking for first (before the dash).

You can do this in XPath or from python. If you want to do it in XPath, only select the rows which contain the home team name.

```
//table[@class="tblContent"]/tr[
    contains(substring-before(.//td[3]/text(), "-"), "AIK")
  or
    contains(substring-before(.//td[3]/text(), "-"), "Djurgårdens IF")
]
```

You can savely remove all whitespace (including newlines), I just added them for readability.

For python you should be able to do much the same, maybe even more concise using some regular expressions.

Comment: I'm getting "invalid syntax" when using that code. Exactly how would the rows variable look like?

Comment: I guess that was because I was using single quotes inside the XPath expression which you're using for declaring strings in python. Exchange your XPath expression for selecting the table rows by my one, that's all you've got to do.

Comment: "rows = hxs.select('//table[@class="tblContent"]/tr[contains(substring-before(.//td[3]/text(), "-"), "AIK") or contains(substring-before(.//td[3]/text(), "-"), "Djurgårdens IF")]')"

Results in exceptions.ValueError: All string must be XML compatible: Uniccode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control chracters.

Answer (score 1):

A few points to note:

1. `string` is a built-in type, so it's generally good practice to avoid using it for your own variables
2. Removing whitespace was indeed the way to clean up `home_team` enough to do a straight comparison with the required "AIK". I used `string.strip()` on `home_team` and `away_team` as it's a little cleaner than `string.replace(" ", "")` but that's a personal thing
3. I also added a ":" between the home and away teams in the `print` lines to distinguish between them more clearly when I was testing, so feel free to get rid of that change

Have a check and let me know if there are any other issues. :)

```
   def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        rows = hxs.select('//table[@class="tblContent"]/tr')

        for row in rows:
            item = SchemaItem()
            item['date'] = row.select('.//td[2]/div/span/text()').extract()
            item['teams'] = row.select('.//td[3]/text()').extract()

            for fixture in item['teams']:
                teams = fixture.split('-') #split it
                home_team = teams[0].strip()
                away_team = teams[1].strip()

                if home_team == "AIK":
                    for fixDate in item['date']:
                            year = fixDate[0:4]
                            month = fixDate[5:7]
                            day = fixDate[8:10]
                            hour = fixDate[11:13]
                            minute = fixDate[14:16]
                            print year, month, day, hour, minute, home_team, ":", away_team
                elif home_team == u"Djurgårdens IF":
                    for fixDate in item['date']:
                        year = fixDate[0:4]
                        month = fixDate[5:7]
                        day = fixDate[8:10]
                        hour = fixDate[11:13]
                        minute = fixDate[14:16]
                        print year, month, day, hour, minute, home_team, ":", away_team
```