# Scrapy web crawler not returning anything

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm working on Scrapy for the first time and I can't get this to return anything. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from idcode.items import StatuteItem

class IdCodeSpider(BaseSpider):
  name = "idcode"
  allowed_domains = ["idaho.gov"]
  start_urls = ["http://legislature.idaho.gov/idstat/Title1/T1CH1SECT1-101.htm"]

  def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = StatuteItem()
    item['title'] = hxs.select("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/text()").extract()
    return item
```

I know everything else in my project is working because if I add `item['title'] = "test"` above `return item` it returns "test". So I must have something wrong with my XPath, but I tested that in the Chrome Developer Console and it's working there.

Comment: You should give us also the HTML code to verify your xpath

Comment: The url is http://legislature.idaho.gov/idstat/Title1/T1CH1SECT1-101.htm

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does my XPath query (scraping HTML tables) only work in Firebug, but not the application I'm developing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the). Additionally, that site has horrible bad markup, which gets parsed differently by different HTML-to-XML-parsers. Try to construct the XPath manually or dump the parsed XML to construct the XPath. And: All you gave us was a path which does not work as intended; what part of the page do you need?

Comment: I'm after the text inside `<div class=" x-title-1-0">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `tbody` resolved the issue.

```
item['title'] = hxs.select("//table/tr[1]/td[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/text()").extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the code and not only to create it, you can use Goose project. It is only for text and media but I have used it many times and I don't have any problem.

Here is the link:

https://github.com/grangier/python-goose