# Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression

Tags: php, xpath

I'm an Xpath newbie. I want to loop through the result of a cURL query and print each  element of the only table on the page.

I've used the Xpath plugin for Firefox to obtain my expression and my table is structured as follows:

```
<table>
<tr class="listItemOneBg">
    <td valign="top">
        SMITH
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        WILLIAM C C
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        Male
    </td>
    <td valign="top">

    </td>
    <td valign="top">

    </td>
    <td valign="top">

    </td>
    <td valign="top">

    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        BLACKWOOD
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        61
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        1924
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <a target="_blank" href='XXX'>
            order</a>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="listItemTwoBg">
    <td valign="top">
        SMITH
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        WILLIAM C PAGE-
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        Male
    </td>
    <td valign="top">

    </td>
    <td valign="top">

    </td>
    <td valign="top">

    </td>
    <td valign="top">

    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        SWAN
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        9
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        1914
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <a target="_blank" href='XXY'>
            order</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's the code I've tried so far. I get a message"Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". What am I doing wrong?

```
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Create new PHP DOM document
$dom = new DOMDocument;
// Load html from curl request into document model
@$dom->loadHTML($page);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$tableRows = $xpath->query("id('divResults')/table/tbody/tr");
foreach ($tableRows as $row) {
     // fetch all 'tds' inside this 'tr'
    $td = $xpath->query('td', $row);
    echo $td->item(1)->textContent;
}
```

Comment: Why have you put extra single quotes around the XPath? What's the deal with the `x:` prefixes?

Comment: I've updated my code. As for the prefixes, I've used the output of the Xpath plugin to give me my expressions.

Comment: My expression now works although I cant loop yet

Comment: @user1801060 Try fetching all the way to `td` in one query. And see if it works. Also try `'//td'` in the second.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my XPath query (scraping HTML tables) only work in Firebug, but not the application I'm developing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the)

Comment: Additionally: The HTML snippet should be containing the element (a div?) having that id.

Comment: If you're editing your question very strongly, and it already contains other answers, you should somehow post that as a comment to prevent confusion like in @CodeAngry's answer -- or even maybe ask another question (the "one big" problem of your first question actually was solved).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the table you're after is actually in a `<div id="divResults">`...

```
$tableRows = $xpath->query('//div[@id="divResults"]/table/tbody/tr');
foreach ($tableRows as $row) {
    $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
}
```

Comment: Bless you! You've saved me several hours of grief

Comment: @user1801060 +1. And this is a proper XPath expression. Not the peculiar `ID('...')` thing you used which is the first time I've ever seen.

Comment: what is the expression for `<div class="scheduleWrap><table><tbody><tr><td width="20%">`? this expression is returning false `$time = $path->query('//div[@class="scheduleWrap"]/table/tbody/tr');`

Comment: @BannedfromSO Make sure the actual HTML source has a `<tbody>` tag. Your browser's inspector tab is not an accurate representation of the source document

Comment: What so ever the PHP code going to read HTML doc on browser, so it should work and I realized what might have happen inside, but this is how I fixed. **`html tag which is enclosing the targetted content to extract, into $your_dom_obj_var->query('//HTML_ELEMENT[@ATTRIBUTE="VALUE"'])`** thats it nothing much after it.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>**That's a non-standard XPath expression.** It cannot work in `DOMXPath`.</strike>
*(Downvoters, the expression has been edited since the question was posted. Cheers!)*

This is where you learn `XPath`:

- [Microsoft **XPath Syntax**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471.aspx)
- [Microsoft **XPath by Example**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx)

**PS**: *It's where I learnt it.*

Comment: This is a standard XPath 1.0 (and upwards) expression which is totally fine in DOMXPath, apart not matching the input document.

Comment: No, it's not non-standard. Just because it's not in the examples you used to learn XPath doesn't make it non-standard. Read the spec.

Comment: @MichaelKay Homie, the question has been thoroughly edited since I posted this. I left the answer here for other who need sources to learn XPath properly. Don't -1 when you're late at the party.

Comment: @JensErat My comment to MK goes to you too. Regards!

Comment: Sorry. This is a real weakness of StackOverflow, that people are allowed to change the question and thus make nonsense of existing answers. Take the downvote as a signal to future readers to mean "don't make use of this answer", not as a criticism of the person who contributed the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, too. You also might want to briefly reason your answer in future and somewhat reference the broken query (by fixing it) -- then the edit would have been realized and as is, your answer wouldn't go for a great answer anyway (but no reason for downvote yet). It _could_ even be flagged as "not an answer" as it's mainly a reference and does not attempt to solve the question.