# Xpath not working properly

Tags: xml, xpath, xhtml, lxml, python-requests

I am working with lxml and requests to scrape  data for a language development program for some of my friends who want to learn English . So i am currently working with the slang learning part of the program , I'll just skip to the main problem now.

Here is a [sample page](http://www.englishdaily626.com/slang.php?054) which i am using to demonstrate my problem.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
def make_tree(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
    page = requests.post(url,headers=headers)
    return html.fromstring(page.text)

url = 'http://www.englishdaily626.com/slang.php?054'

t = make_tree(url)
print t.xpath('/html/body/p/table/tbody/tr/td/table[4]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/p/span/text()')
```

this just gives me a blank list . My xpath is correct if checked in xpath viewer firefox. what is the problem then ? and is occuring everywhere expect for href .

Comment: This may be due to changes which are made by scripting elements in the page. I would suggest to do the following: download the 'raw' page using wget. Then check if you can find your XPath expression in there.

Comment: @marcus thanks dude but i've tried that , it didn't work

Comment: maybe there something to do with namespaces , i'm trying learn about it ..

Comment: What do you mean by _it din't work_? You could find the XPath expression in the downloaded raw file?

Comment: I've setup a test environment on my machine. The problem already occurs at level `/html/body/p/table` which is empty although `/html/body/p` returns a result set with three `<p>` nodes in it and the first `<p>` definitely has a `<table>` in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my XPath query (scraping HTML tables) only work in Firebug, but not the application I'm developing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the)

Comment: There is no `<tbody/>` element in that page, firebug adds it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the/18241030#18241030.

Comment: I think there's a combination of problems. First, @JensErat is right. There are no `<tbody>` tags in the raw file. Second, the correction algorithm of `lxml` is apparently not able to handle the non-closed `<p>` tags at level 3. My browser says there are five `<p>` tags and one `<form>` tag below the `<body>` tag. `lxml` thinks there are three `<p>` tags, two `<table>` tags and one `<form>` tag. I think it would be wiser to phrase the XPath more logically using attribute values than structurally. Could you tell us which experpt exactly you are looking for?

Comment: @Markus after removing all the `/tbody`  elements and the starting `/p` element it works like a charm . Thanks for sticking up with me buddy !!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a more flexible, general XPath query. If you're looking for the first definition, you could use this:

```
'//tr[td[1]/p/b/span = "Definition:"][1]/td[2]/p/span/text()'
```

This works in a browser and with lxml in your example script.