# Extracting an Id from html table response in jmeter

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I need to extract an Id (100000010) in an html response which is a table as shown below:

```
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<B>
100000010
</B>
</td>
</tr>
</tr>
```

Following xpath extractor to get this:

```
//*[@id="screenlet_1_col"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/b
```

which is exactly what chrome gave me. But I am not able to get the value in the variable in XPath extractor.

Any help?

Comment: Your HTML is no HTML (there should not be nested `<tr/>` tags) and does not match to your query. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the and build the expression on your own / match it to the original HTML (or better, to the tree it will be parsed).

Comment: What about '//*[@id="screenlet_1_col"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/b/text()'?

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS/JQuery extractor, to give you the expression you need to show the full HTML. It seems based on XPath you only show part of HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

XPath extractor with default settings will work for **valid XML or XHTML only**.

If your document isn't XML-compliant you'll need to check ["Use Tidy" box in your XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

Small example:

Given following test plan structure:

- Thread Group with 1 thread and 1 loop
- HTTP Request to "google.com" host with "/" path and parameter "q" = "test" (or whatever)
- Xpath Extractor with "Reference Name" = "link" and "Xpath query" = "//a"

will give you nothing on default as Google Search Results Page isn't valid XHTML.

But when you set "Use Tidy" you'll get all links as JMeter Variables with "link_" prefix like

```
link_1=something
link_2=something else
link_3=....
```

Hope this helps