# Retrieve information from table rows using xpath in scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to use scrapy in order to exrtact information from an html table and store them into database. The information is stored into rows and there is no way to distinct one record from the other. (the site I'm crawling is the http://www.ets.gr/frontoffice/portal.asp?cpage=NODE&cnode=12).

How can I loop to every row of the table and get information if the form of:

**Record1: tr[1] and tr[2] (skip tr[3]) 

Record2: tr[4] and tr[5] (skip tr[6]) 

Record3: tr[7] and tr[8] (skip tr[9])** 

and so...?

The nodes I'm getting in order to loop for each one are: 
**nodes = hxs.xpath("//table/tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr")**

Comment: '/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[@valign="top"]'

Comment: @metaphy see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructing these results is not possible using XPath 1.0 (and that's all scrapy supports), you will have to use Python code for that (after pulling the information using XPath).

If you want to omit the third/sixth/... row from the start, use `position()` and modulo:

```
//table/tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[(position() mod 3) != 0]
```

Alternatively, use the `@valign` attribute like metaphy proposed:

```
//table/tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[@valign = 'top']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I finally manage to scrap this table using conditional statements and append the items at the end of each loop using a flag.