# Trying to retrieve text only from a div with xpath

Tags: php, html, regex, xpath

I'm trying to write a document that will go through a webpage that was poorly coded and return the title element. However, the person who made the website I plan on scraping did not use ANY classes, simply just div elements. Heres the source webpage I'm trying to scrape:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style = "...">
<div style = "...">
<div style = "...">TEXT I WANT</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

and when I copy the xpath in chrome I get this string:

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div[3]
```

I'm having trouble figuring out where I put that string in an xpath query.
If not an xpath query maybe I should do a preg_match?

I tried this:

```
$location = '/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div[3]';
$html = file_get_contents($URL);
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
// Now query the document:
foreach ($xpath->query($location) as $node) {
  echo $node, "\n";
}
```

but nothing is printed to the page.

Thanks.

EDIT: Full sourse code here:
http://pastebin.com/K5tZ4dFH

EDIT2: Cleaner code screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9mDg.png

Comment: Try echo `$node->item(0);` inside the loop.

Comment: nothing being output still. The page isn't very cleanly coded, may I need to clean up the DOM? Other codes seemed to have something to clean it up but the method error'd out and I couldn't find any documentation on the method. @Rikesh

Comment: @hwnd its above in the code, but the code is so messy I tried to just shorten it down. edited with a pastebin to source

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my XPath query (scraping HTML tables) only work in Firebug, but not the application I'm developing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your source, try the following:

```
$html = file_get_contents($URL);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html); 

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@style, 'left:20px')]");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
   echo $node->textContent;
}
```

Comment: Yea I just reduced the source code down because it was messy. I added a pastebin of the sourcecode if you can make sense of it.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/lWKheBy.png
Maybe this image will help, it shows the code a little more organized.
I'm trying to get the title of something off a site.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the text just before the first `</div>`, so this regex will find that:

```
[^<>]+(?=<\/div>)
```

Here's a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/j8FmDtMTfF).