# xpath doesn't work in this website

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I am scraping individual listing pages from [justproperty.com](http://www.justproperty.com/) (individual listing from the original question no longer active).

I want to get the value of the **Ref**

this is my xpath:

```
>>> sel.xpath('normalize-space(.//div[@class="info_div"]/table/tbody/tr/td[norma
lize-space(text())="Ref:"]/following-sibling::td[1]/text())').extract()[0]
```

This has no results in scrapy, despite working in my browser.

Comment: By requiring folks who want to test proposed answers to your question to write their own code to actually download the document, you're decreasing the number and quality of answers you're likely to get. It would be helpful if you provided a proper SSCCE for your problem (see http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I had a problem, i tried to solve it. I couldn't. So, I asked here. the question is so clear

Comment: It's clear, but it requires more work for people to test their answers than it would if your reproducer were self-contained.

Comment: @alecxe how did you test the xpath in the browser please? would you tell me because I have never done that before. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works perfectly in `lxml.html` (with modern Scrapy uses):

```
sel.xpath('.//div[@class="info_div"]//td[text()="Ref:"]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()')
```

Note that I'm using `//` to get between the `div` and the `td`, not laying out the explicit path. I'd have to take a closer look at the document to grok why, but the path given in that area was incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Don't create XPath expression by looking at Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools, they're changing the markup. Remove the `/tbody` axis step and you'll receive exactly what you're look for.

```
normalize-space(.//div[@class="info_div"]/table/tr/td[
  normalize-space(text())="Ref:"
]/following-sibling::td[1]/text())
```

Read [Why does my XPath query (scraping HTML tables) only work in Firebug, but not the application I'm developing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Another XPath that gets the same thing: `(.//td[@class='titles']/../td[2])[1]`

I tried your XPath using [XPath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/) and it works fine.

Comment: Works against the browser DOM doesn't mean it works against the original document.