# How to verify an XPath expression in Chrome Developers tool or Firefox's Firebug?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

How can I verify my XPath?

I am using Chrome Developers tool to inspect the elements and form my XPath. I verify it using the Chrome plugin XPath Checker, however it does not always give me the result. What is a better way to verify my XPath.

I have also tried using Firebug to inspect the bug and also using the FirePath to verify. But does Firepath also verify the XPath.

My last option would be to use the Selenium WebDriver to confirm my XPath.

Answer (score 471, accepted):

## Chrome

This can be achieved by three different approaches (see my blog article [here](http://yizeng.me/2014/03/23/evaluate-and-validate-xpath-css-selectors-in-chrome-developer-tools/) for more details):

- Search in `Elements` panel like below
- Execute `$x()` and `$$()` in `Console` panel, as shown in Lawrence's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22571294/1177636)
- Third party extensions (not really necessary in most of the cases, could be an overkill)

Here is how you search XPath in `Elements` panel:

1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open Chrome Developer Tool
2. In "Elements" panel, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
3. In the search box, type in XPath or CSS Selector, if elements are found, they will be highlighted in yellow.

[image]

## Firefox (since version 75)

Since FF 75 it's possible to use raw xpath query without evaluation xpath expressions, see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_HTML#XPath_search) for more info.

## Firefox (prior version 75)

1. Either select "Web Console" from the Web Developer submenu in the 
   Firefox Menu (or Tools menu if you display the menu bar or are on Mac OS X)
   or press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> on OS X) keyboard shortcut.
2. In the command line at the bottom use the following:

   - `$()`: Returns the first element that matches. Equivalent to `document.querySelector()` or calls the `$` function in the page, if it exists.
   - `$$()`: Returns an array of DOM nodes that match. This is like for `document.querySelectorAll()`, but returns an array instead of a `NodeList`.
   - `$x()`: Evaluates an XPath expression and returns an array of matching nodes.

---

## Firefox (prior version 49)

1. Install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)
2. Install [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/)
3. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open Firebug
4. Switch to `FirePath` panel
5. In dropdown, select XPathor CSS
6. Type in to locate

[image]

Comment: Just one warning on XPath and browsers, as this leads to lots of confusion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the

Comment: @JensErat: Really good point. For others reading this comment, as already mentioned in that question, Selenium is not affected because it drives browsers and uses the same underlying JavaScript evaluation technology with dev tools.

Comment: @user1177636: What software did you use for generating these GIFs?

Comment: If you need a local parser for XQuery too I've found BaseX: http://basex.org/products/

Comment: Answer needs an update for Firefox. Unfortunately Firebug is obsolete and has been merged into Developer Tools. Currently you can test xpath expression in Console, e.g. `$("//div")`

Comment: derloopkat's answer is the best for me, but it's missing an "x" - it should be `$x("//div")`. XPath expressions can be tested in the console with `$x("expr")` and css expressions with `$$("expr")`

Comment: Chrome `$$()` function not work for XPath

Answer (score 81):

You can open the DevTools in Chrome with <kbd>CTRL+I</kbd> on Windows (or <kbd>CMD+I</kbd> Mac), and Firefox with <kbd>F12</kbd>, then select the `Console` tab), and check the XPath by typing `$x("your_xpath_here")`.
This will return an array of matched values. If it is empty, you know there is no match on the page.

#### Firefox v66 (April 2019):

[image: Firefox v66 console xpath]

#### Chrome v69 (April 2019):

[image: Chrome v69 console xpath]

Comment: This method isn't ideal but it is good to know because whatever xpath expression you write in that console can be executed by a JavascriptExecutor in Selenium.  Sometimes you can use that as a workaround, perhaps when Firefox native events are disabled?

Comment: @djangofan, how do you mean? By that logic both of these answers, although correct, are unnecessary by your logic.

Comment: @bosnjak when trying this in console `$x("//input[@name='q']")` I got `VM251:1 Uncaught TypeError: $x is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:1`

Comment: @YasserKhalil which browser are you using, which version? What site are you doing this on?

Answer (score 24):

**By using Chrome or Opera**

**without any plugins, without writing any single XPath syntax character**

1. right click the required element, then "inspect"
2. right click on highlighted element tag, choose *Copy* → *Copy XPath*.

;)

[image]

Comment: For Chrome, this is the BEST solution I have seen yet. Thanks for sharing. Makes it easier to confirm in Chrome when I don't wish to use Firefox.

Comment: I have used this to great benefit. But the one big problem is that sometimes the context menu is disabled or overwritten. Then you have to rely on the other approaches.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It isn't verifying an existing xpath, it's generating one. The one that Chrome generates is often ugly and very fragile when a much better solution exists.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method I use to quickly visualize XPATH results within a HTML webpage - which as of HTML5 is technically an XML document (see note).

1. Open DevTools (F12)
2. Go to Console and type the following:

   `$x("//p[a]").forEach(myFancyResult => myFancyResult.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow');`

`//p[a]` is an XPath expression that selects all <p> elements that contain <a> elements. The result is an array which is fed into the forEach method, from which we modify the elements backgroundColor.

[image]

**Note:**
The method is problematic against an XML document opened locally because the browser will apply a default style sheet to view the XML document with pretty colors and give you the ability to collapse and expand the document; This effectively wraps the XML document in div or span tags which messes up the original XML document, making this technique somewhat useless.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to check your xpath is to use **selenium IDE.**

1. Install Firefox Selenium IDE
2. Open your application in FireFox and open IDE
3. In IDE, on a new line, paste your xpath to the target and click
   Find. The corresponding element would be highlighted in your
   application

[image: Selenium IDE]

Answer (score 0):

I verify XPath and CSS selectors using [WebSync Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/natu-websync/aohpgnblncapofbobbilnlfliihianac).

It provides possibility to verify selectors and also to generate/modify selectors by clicking on element attributes.

*https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/natu-websync/aohpgnblncapofbobbilnlfliihianac*

[image]

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Answer (score 0):

you can verify it using `document.querySelector("YOUR X PATH HERE")` on the chrome console