# picking element in firebug for use in selenium

Tags: selenium

Any idea how to select an element using Selenium and this output i Firebug:

```
<tr class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even ui-datatable-selectable" aria-selected="false" role="row" data-rk="0101" data-ri="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome, lots easier. Locate the element, then open context menu with right click, Copy -> XPath. Tutorial with images: [How to verify an XPath expression in Chrome Developers tool or Firefox's Firebug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571267/how-to-verify-an-xpath-expression-in-chrome-developers-tool-or-firefoxs-firebug)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) plugin for Firefox, which is add-on with dependency of `Firebug`

You can evaluate both `XPATH` & `cssSelectors`.