# count element in webelement

Tags: selenium, countelements

I want to count elements in selenium.
When using xpath `//*[@class='z-listbox-body']/table/tbody[2]/tr` I get 3 matching nodes.

But my code gets 12 instead of 3:

```
public String countTable(){
    List<WebElement> located_elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='z-listbox-body']/table/tbody[2]/tr"));
    int count = 0;
    for(WebElement located_element:located_elements){
        count ++;
    }
    String s = String.valueOf(count);

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Does `located_elements.size()` also return 12, or 3?

Comment: So which one is correct _using xpath `//*[@class='z-listbox-body']/table/tbody[2]/tr` or your code_?

Comment: What is the number of matching elements when you search with your XPath expression in ChromeDevelopers Tools? How to check that see: :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571267/how-to-verify-an-xpath-expression-in-chrome-developers-tool-or-firefoxs-firebug

Comment: Frank, I get 3 matching nodes , but my code gets 12 .:(

Comment: When you are debugging the code and have a look on the content of the list, what is inside this list? How are this webelements looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use below code:

```
public String countTable(WebDriver dirver){ 
    List located_elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[@class='z-listbox-body']/table/tbody[2]/tr")); 
    return String.valuseOf(located_elements.size());
```

}

Comment: What have you changed - removed the typing on List and use .size() instead of manually counting the contents of the list? Can you explain why the for loop would give the wrong answer?

Comment: when i search in web result 3 matching nodes. i try List located_elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[@class='z-listbox-body']/table/tbody[2]/tr")); return String.valuseOf(located_elements.size()); but my code gets 12 instead of 3: