# Can't find the right Xpath

Tags: xpath

Please, anyone can help me to find the right XPath to retreive the date value "07/05/2018 04:45"

```
<input type="text" id="startDate" name="myDate" value="07/05/2018 04:45" class="field1 center" onclick="pickDate(this,$PT('startDate'));" onkeydown="if (window.event.keyCode==13) return false;">
```

I've tried without succeed:

/input[@type="text"]@value

//*[@id="startDate"]

Comment: Did you try `/*/input/@value`?

Comment: Try to use following xpath
//input[@id='startDate']/@value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first suggest using one of these methods to verify you're able to select the right item:  [How to verify an XPath expression in Chrome Developers tool or Firefox's Firebug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571267/how-to-verify-an-xpath-expression-in-chrome-developers-tool-or-firefoxs-firebug/22571294)

Then try this:

```
//*[@id='startDate']/@value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can locate element from Id or any attribute like,

```
//input[@value='07/05/2018 04:45']
```

OR

```
//input[@id='startDate']
```

As according to your Binding language, you can retrieve value from getAttribute submethod something like

```
(above locator).getAttribute("value")
```

So defined locator will locate and it will get value of inner attribute from attribute name "value" which you want to achieve.

Hope it will help you to retrieve it.