# How to verify xpath in real android device using uiautomator like 22571267

Tags: android, selenium, appium

How to verify XPath in real android device using uiautomator?

Basically we verify XPath in Chrome using inspect element (see [22571267](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571267/how-to-verify-an-xpath-expression-in-chrome-developers-tool-or-firefoxs-firebug))

Is there any way to do this for an Android device?

Comment: as far as i know, you can verify the xpath's while debugging, you can try out different xpaths there. The browser like facility is not there in appium inspector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use appium inspector for getting

1. Exact xpath or id for the selected node
2. You can even try tap,sendKeys to test your xpath.
3. Recorder facility
4. Inspector to inspect each individual element like chrome inspector

[image]

If you want to learn how to use it in detail follow this [link](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-desktop-inspector/)