# Extract ratings with XPath

Tags: xpath

How to extract all the ratings(numbers) with XPath from the following page? Thank you. 
[Top 50 best films of 2018](https://imdb.com/list/ls021105452/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If to find only by class of `<span>` that contains rating, then you will get a lot of other items. So I selected the parent `<div>` by class and then got the `<span>` by class. It seems to work fine.

```
//div[@class="ipl-rating-star small"]/span[@class="ipl-rating-star__rating"]/text()
```

Useful info:

- [XPath tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)
- [How to use XPath in Chrome DevTools or else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22573161/7128891)

Comment: Thank you. May I ask the technique to find that?

Comment: Well, I [use Chrome Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22573161/7128891). I inspected the rating element, so I got it in Elements Tab. First thing I tried - was to find by class of the found `<span>`. But it didn't work. So I used parent element, as described in answer, and it worked.

Comment: May I also ask where and how do you check the results?

Comment: If you open Chrome DevTools > Elements tab, press Ctrl+F and paste XPath from answer, it will highlight 100 elements(ratings) in the HTML (because there are 100 movies on the page).

Comment: Also you can use Javascript in Console tab. Just execute `$x('//div[@class="ipl-rating-star small"]/span[@class="ipl-rating-star__rating"]/text()').map(x => x.data)` and you will get the array or ratings.

Comment: You helped a lot. Will try it tomorrow, now I don’t have access to my computer.

Comment: Is it possoble to export the mapping from console?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with Javascript. If you need more answers - better ask new question and include more details and tools you use.