# Selenium Script Fails even though Xpath , Firebug show the correct element

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I had a question . When i "inspect" this particular element and take "exact" xpath and copy it to my selenium script and run my script, it fails to identify?

Any idea how to do it?
Repeating again, i copied the exact xpath , tried inspecting element. All correct. Still :(

Thanks,
S.K

Comment: Can you provide link to the webpage or complete HTML code snippet of the webpage?

Comment: This link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Selenium fails to find an element you know is present, commonly the problem is with synchronization: Selenium tries  to access the element too fast, before it appears on the page (and when you try to inspect element even a second later, you can see it, since it was rendered by then). Try to WAIT for the very same element before doing anything else. Examples of the wait  [can be found here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)