# How to list all TD elements containing a SPAN?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack, fizzler

I'm trying to parse a website in C# using Fizzler. My goal is to get this element: 
/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[18]/td[2]/span (FireBug XPath).

The problem is that the TR and TD numbers are not fixed. All I know that I always need the LAST span, in the LAST TD, in the LAST TR :)

I was trying with this, but all I get is NULL:

```
HtmlWeb document = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = document.Load("http://websiteaddress.com/site-name.html");

HtmlNodeCollection tableDatas = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tbody/tr/td/span").Last();
```

This is the TABLE I'm trying to parse. I only need the content of the last span in the last td of the last row.

```
<table id="ctl00_WebPartManager1_blablabla_ctl00_tblRates" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" rules="all" border="1" style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <th></th><th><span>USD</span></th>
                </tr><tr>
                    <th></th><th><span>USA $</span></th>
                </tr><tr>
                    <th></th><th><span>1</span></th>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 03.</span></td><td><span>227,31 </span></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 04.</span></td><td><span>226,79 </span></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 05.</span></td><td><span>225,66 </span></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 06.</span></td><td><span>225,03 </span></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 07.</span></td><td><span>223,14 </span></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 10.</span></td><td><span>224,63 </span></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 11.</span></td><td><span>226,06 </span></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 12.</span></td><td><span>226,53 </span></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 13.</span></td><td><span>223,63 </span></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 14.</span></td><td><span>225,74 </span></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 17.</span></td><td><span>224,67 </span></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 18.</span></td><td><span>224,65 </span></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 19.</span></td><td><span>223,26 </span></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 20.</span></td><td><span>225,94 </span></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 21.</span></td><td><span>226,25 </span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

This is the result I get from the document.load() method (it's kinda messed up...):

```
    <table id="ctl00_WebPartManager1_blablabla_ctl00_tblRates" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" rules="all" border="1" style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <th><th><span>USD</span>
                <tr>
                    <th><th><span>USA $</span>
                <tr>
                    <th><th><span>1</span>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 03.</span><td><span>227,31 </span>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 04.</span><td><span>226,79 </span>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 05.</span><td><span>225,66 </span>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 06.</span><td><span>225,03 </span>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 07.</span><td><span>223,14 </span>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 10.</span><td><span>224,63 </span>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 11.</span><td><span>226,06 </span>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 12.</span><td><span>226,53 </span>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 13.</span><td><span>223,63 </span>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 14.</span><td><span>225,74 </span>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 17.</span><td><span>224,67 </span>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 18.</span><td><span>224,65 </span>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 19.</span><td><span>223,26 </span>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 20.</span><td><span>225,94 </span>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>2014. 03. 21.</span><td><span>226,25 </span>

            </td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></th></th></tr></th></th></tr></th></th></tr></table>
```

Can someone help me out, please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is this part of your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the

Comment: Well, looking at the input you provided: yes, it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the `<tbody>` element [being introduced by the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the), but not by HTML Agility Pack (this is why you don't receive any results at all); use `[last()` predicates to access the last child in the current element.

```
//table/tr[last()]/td[last()]/span[last()]
```

You can also query the last span of all, but this will probably a little bit slower as it has to construct the whole result set before:

```
(//table/tr/td/span)[last()]
```

Using `.Last();` in C# would be even slightly worse, as the result set even has to be constructed as a C# array before omitting all but the last value.

Comment: You're right, it was the problem :) My only question is why it's returning the date (2014. 03. 21.) not the rate? So I assume it's fetching the first TD, not the last.

Comment: You must be querying the wrong data or the rates are not in the input. This query definitely should return the last rate, and does for me (testing in BaseX).

Comment: Updated my question with result I get from the Load() function. I think the problem is the messed up table stucture...

Comment: The HTML does not close tags correctly. Try `//table/tr//span[last()]` which ignores the actual tree structure and fetches the last span element per table row.

Comment: Yeah, the TR-s are now nested in each other... Total mess. Your code returns: USD. So, it's not going through the TRs until the last span :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `last()` instead of exact element position to get the last element in result set :

```
//table/tr[last()]/td[last()]/span[last()]
```

Above XPath will get the last `<tr>`, then look for the last `<td>` in that `<tr>`, then look for the last `<span>` in that `<td>`.

If this isn't what you're looking for, I'd suggest to post sample html to make it easier for us to better understand the problem.

Comment: Thank you, this returns for me also NULL, but I added the table data into my question post.