# Xpath nested tables

Tags: php, xpath

I have a Table, see Code. Its a table that has a table in it, so its nested. Now i want to get all vales of the parent table only and then all values of the child table.

To get the childs data i can do this:

```
$query = '//*[@id="WordClass"]/table[2]/tr/td[2]/table/tr';

$nodes = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($nodes as $node) { //do more querys to get the td data and save it..
```

My problem is how to only get the data of the parent table without getting the child data/tr/td also.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr valign="top">
    <td>
        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="colTitle" align="center" colspan="4">
                    Da Titel
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="colTitle" align="center" colspan="2">One
                </td>
                <td class="colTitle" align="center" colspan="2">Two
                    I
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="colSubTitle">Pe</td>
                <td class="colSubTitle">Ve</td>
                <td class="colSubTitle">Pe</td>
                <td class="colSubTitle">Ve</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="rowTitle">x</td>
                <td class="colVerbDef">y</td>
                <td class="rowTitle">z</td>
                <td class="colVerbDef">c</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="rowTitle">r</td>
                <td class="colVerbDef">t</td>
                <td class="rowTitle">z</td>
                <td class="colVerbDef">z</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="colTitle" align="center" colspan="4">
                    Da Titel2
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="colTitle" align="center" colspan="2">One
                </td>
                <td class="colTitle" align="center" colspan="2">Two
                    I
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="colSubTitle">Pe2</td>
                <td class="colSubTitle">Ve2</td>
                <td class="colSubTitle">Pe2</td>
                <td class="colSubTitle">Ve2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="rowTitle">x2</td>
                <td class="colVerbDef">y2</td>
                <td class="rowTitle">z2</td>
                <td class="colVerbDef">c2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="rowTitle">r2</td>
                <td class="colVerbDef">t2</td>
                <td class="rowTitle">z2</td>
                <td class="colVerbDef">z2</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: As the XPath and your data don't match, I suspect you could have a quite common XPath browser problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the for more information

Comment: ah sorry posted the wrong xpath. it is just a part of the whole html code. dint want to post it all here. but the question i still valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the contents of the parent table's `td` elements using a direct path from the root:

```
/table/tbody/tr/td
```

The contents of those cells happen to be another `table` element, but you can strip those out with DOMDocument.

To get the inner tables' `td` elements only excluding the parents, you can look for tables that have a td parent, then select its `td`s:

```
//td/table//td
```

If I've misunderstood your question, please feel free to explain further and I will update.