# PHP DOMXPath gives empty string for /@ID

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

Simplified HTML

```
<tr>
<td class="orderOverviewAnotherColumn">0177-4066356</td>
<a name="orderTableSorted:orderTable:10:j_id504" id="orderTableSorted:orderTable:10:j_id504" href="#">
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="orderOverviewAnotherColumn">0177-4066357</td>
<a name="orderTableSorted:orderTable:11:j_id504" id="orderTableSorted:orderTable:11:j_id504" href="#">
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="orderOverviewAnotherColumn">0177-4066358</td>
<a name="orderTableSorted:orderTable:12:j_id504" id="orderTableSorted:orderTable:12:j_id504" href="#">
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="orderOverviewAnotherColumn">0177-4066359</td>
<a name="orderTableSorted:orderTable:13:j_id504" id="orderTableSorted:orderTable:13:j_id504" href="#">
</tr>
```

Using the following Code in PHP

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('448713409.html');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$vRes = $xpath->query(".//*[@id='orderTableSorted:orderTable:tbody_element']/tr[contains(.,'4066356')]//a[contains(@id,':j_id504')]/@ID");

foreach ($vRes as $obj) {
    $clean[] = $obj->nodeValue;
}

$clink = implode(" ",$clean);
var_dump($clink);
```

returns...

```
string(0) ""
```

Using Firebug Xpath Checker it returns the ID "orderTableSorted:orderTable:**10**:j_id504" which i need to find.

Any Help in the right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath is a case-sensitive language. Therefore, `id` and `ID` are entirely different things. In your HTML sample, the `a` elements have an attribute `id`, but none that is called `ID`. That's why the query does not yield any results.

Lowercase `ID` at the very end of your path expression:

```
//a[contains(@id,':j_id504')]/@id
```

I doubt that Firebug returns an uppercase `ID` when in the actual HTML there is none.

Comment: Actually in the Xpath Checker both, /@ID and /@id work. But your Solution did the Trick, thank you very much!

Comment: Then, you should consider filing a bug to the Firebug developers, in my opinion.

Comment: Just FYI: When you use `DOMDocument::loadHTML()` PHP's **DOMDocument** is in HTML-mode and element and attribute names are case insensitive. This is also true `DOMXPath` then.

Comment: @hakre Thanks for this info! But then I do not think I understand why lowercasing `id` "does the trick", as user3523440 says. Also, if DOMDocument is case-insensitive, why are you sure that DOMXPath is, too?

Comment: I have to correct my self a little: The xpath expression needs to be written with lowercase element und attribute names. Currently playing around with this a little. Just have checked against the case in HTML element and attribute names and for those it doesn't matter. That's also the reason why it does not work with `@ID`. Firefox xpath might be more lax with case.

Comment: @hakre Yes, I'd say that's plausible. Firefox is designed to serve HTML environments, whereas XPath in general is more geared towards XML.