# Right Xpath for HTML elements?

Tags: php, html, xpath, web-scraping

I need to scrape this HTML page ...

http://www1.usl3.toscana.it/default.asp?page=ps&ospedale=3

[image]

.... using PHP and XPath to get the value **7** near the string "**CODICE GIALLO**"

(NOTE: you could see different value in that page if you try to browse it ... it doesn't matter ..,, it change dinamically .... )

I'm using this PHP code sample to print the value ...

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $url = 'http://www1.usl3.toscana.it/default.asp?page=ps&ospedale=3';

    $xpath_for_parsing = '/html/body/div/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/b';

    //#Set CURL parameters: pay attention to the PROXY config !!!!
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '');
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($data);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $colorWaitingNumber = $xpath->query($xpath_for_parsing);
    $theValue =  'N.D.';
    foreach( $colorWaitingNumber as $node )
    {
      $theValue = $node->nodeValue;
    }

    print $theValue;
?>
```

In this way I obtain "**N.D.**" as output not "**7**" as I suppose.

Reading this [Why does my XPath query (scraping HTML tables) only work in Firebug, but not the application I'm developing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the) I've seen that the problem coud be about the `<tbody>` tag so I've tried to eliminate it form my original xpath and I tried my code using:

```
$xpath_for_parsing = '/html/body/div/div[2]/table[2]/tr[1]/td/table/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tr[4]/td[2]/table/tr[2]/td[2]/b'
```

but the result is still "**N.D.**" instead of "**7**".

Using

```
$xpath_for_parsing = '/html/body/div/div[2]/table[2]/tr[1]/td/table/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tr[4]/td[2]/table'
```

the result is "**Codice GIALLO 7**"

How may I obtain only the "**7**" value?

Any suggestions / example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should do the trick:

```
//td[.="Codice GIALLO"]/following-sibling::td/b
```